# How do you build Vue.js single file components and import them when you're not building a single page application?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am building a web application (it's ASP.NET Core 2 MVC but it shouldn't really make any difference here) that is **NOT** a single page application. I am using Vue.js quite happily to provide functionality on the front end via an `Vue` instance. It's got to the point where I need to extract stuff into reusable components, which I can do along side the `Vue` instance like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dev/vue.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
    <my-component message="Hi there!" />
</div>

<script>
    Vue.component('my-component', {
        template: '<p>{{ message }}</p>',
        props: { message: String }
    });

    var app = new Vue({ el: '#app' });
</script>
```

I would love to be able to define my component as one of Vue's single file components (with a `.vue` extension) instead of declaring them like this but all the docs and tutorials I can find focus on single page applications and I am not sure how to modify that information to work for me.

I have had a go with the Vue CLI and worked out how to tell it to build a library rather than a SPA using it's bundled webpack config, but that builds a single `UMD` or `CommonJS` bundle file and I do not know how to make use of it!

I am unfamiliar with webpack, but I am willing to learn. I am currently using Gulp for other stuff in this project, so if I can get away with sticking with Gulp then great, but if I need to switch to webpack I will.

Comment: Vue SFC are pre-processed by `Vue-template-compiler` so in order to use them I would suggest to create a simple `main.js` file which imports all the needed SFC and then point Webpack to this `main.js`. It will produce a bundle - call it `components.js` and then include it as a normal SCRIPT tag on all relevant pages. On each page you will need to instantiate one or more Vue instances for each of your components - just like you do in your example. You can also look at https://github.com/ckhrysze/multipage-vue

Comment: thanks, any chance you could provide an example set up to achieve this? I have spent all afternoon trying to get to grips with webpack but it is... hard :-|

Answer (score 1):

Being able to write your vue components in an SFC-like way is something that can be achieved by using Vue blocks. It allows you to write your multiple components in HTML as follows, without requiring build tools:

```html
<template component="component-name">
    <div>
        <!-- HTML Template here -->
    </div>
    <style scoped>
        /* Scoped styles here */
    </style>
    <script>
        // Vue component definition like in Single File Components.
        export default {
            data() {   
            },
            mounted() {
            },
            methods: {
             
            }
        }
    </script>
</template>
```

More info can be found at:

- Docs: https://fluxfx.nl/vue-blocks/examples/index.html
- Github: https://github.com/j-angnoe/vue-blocks

Comment: That looks like a very promising plugin! I will be sure to give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

I have no example code because I actually develop SPAs only. But you could try to install `vue-cli` (the old 2.x one, not the new 3.x) and then initialize an empty webpack template

```
$ npm install -g vue-cli
$ vue init webpack my-project
$ cd my-project
$ npm install
```

Then you can create your SFCs in the `src` subfolder, then edit `src/main.js`

```
import component1 from './component1.vue'
import component2 from './component2.vue'
```

and then run `npm run build` which will create a `dist` subfolder with `app.js` and some CSS. I am speculating theoretically here as I am using Webpack in different way - it should supposedly work.